# node.js i18n.__ is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization

I am trying to use i18n within my test node.js/express4 server api

I installed i18n-2,
and updated my server.js

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var i18n        = require('i18n-2');

i18n.expressBind(app, {
  // setup some locales - other locales default to en silently
  locales: ['en', 'fr'],
  // set the default locale
  defaultLocale: 'fr',
  // set the cookie name
  cookieName: 'locale'
});

// set up the middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.i18n.setLocaleFromQuery();
  req.i18n.setLocaleFromCookie();
  next();
});

console.log(i18n.__('Hello'));
```

I have added 2 files ./locales/en.js

```
{
 "Hello": "Hello",
}
```

and ./locales/fr.js

```
{
 "Hello": "Salut",
}
```

but when I start my server, I get an error on  `console.log(i18n.__('Hello'));`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i18n` is just a constructor and you need to instantiate it first.
By using `expressBind` you are getting an instance of `i18n` in each `req`.

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var i18n        = require('i18n-2');

i18n.expressBind(app, {
  // setup some locales - other locales default to en silently
  locales: ['en', 'fr'],
  // set the default locale
  defaultLocale: 'fr',
  // set the cookie name
  cookieName: 'locale'
});

// set up the middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.i18n.setLocaleFromQuery();
  req.i18n.setLocaleFromCookie();
  console.log(req.i18n.__("Hello"));
  next();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

If you want to use `i18n` outside of requests, you need to manually create an instance with `new`.